# Can elliptic equations have solutions on non weakly closed subsets?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Assume that $L$ is a elliptic operator defined on a subset $\cal M\subset H_0^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is an open and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ as regular as it is needed. Assume further that there is a well posed PDE $L(u) = f$ that admits a variational approach. In this context, it is very useful to prove that $\cal M$ is weakly closed.

> My question is: is $\cal M$ being weakly closed a necessary condition to $L(u) = f$ to admit a weak solution (not necessarily by Variational Methods)?

Comment: Regarding the question that you just closed. I think I have a proof for the following statement: if $f$ attains values $a$ and $b$, then for any $a<c<b$ there is $\varphi$ so $f\circ\varphi$ is close to $c$ in the $L^p$ norm. Think if this is the question you want. If you state it that way, I will try to sketch a proof, but let me know when the questions is reopened.

Comment: Thank you! I reopened.